# Remove variable name and get value between parentheses in regex

Tags: python, regex, replace

I've been trying to remove the function name, e.g., `1 + abs(10-100) * sqrt(2)`.

I want this to be replaced as `1 + |10-100| * sqrt(2)`.

I've done `abs\(|\)`, it sort of works, but it replaces all of `)` with `|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this

```
import re

input_str = "1 + abs(10-100) * sqrt(2)"
expected_str = re.sub(r'\babs\((.*?)\)', r'| \1 |', input_str)
print(expected_str)
```

`1 + | 10-100 | * sqrt(2)`